# Swift UIGestureRecognizer is not working / is not doing anything

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I have a small issue that I couldn't fix for a few hours now! I have a simple ViewController with a label, which is linked to my ViewController class. I also set up an UIGestureRecognizer to change the text of the label when the label is clicked. But weirdly nothing happens at all. 
The text of the label changes from whatever is set in the Storyboard to "Hello", so the setup is correct. But when I click the label, nothing happens.

Here's the entire ViewController class:

```
import UIKit

class PremiumViewController: UIViewController {

    // Views
    @IBOutlet weak var premiumLabel: UILabel!
    
    // View Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        premiumLabel.text = "Hello"

        // Tap listener
        let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PremiumViewController.clicked))
        premiumLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        premiumLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
    
    @objc func clicked() {
        premiumLabel.text = "You clicked me"
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your label inside a stackview?

Comment: No, it's just a single label constrained to the top left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIGestureRecognizer`

change from

```
let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PremiumViewController.clicked))
```

to

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PremiumViewController.clicked))
```